# Same origin confusion

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

I am confused about what is and what is not possible given the same origin policy. For example, how is a a client-side RSS reader able to grab an RSS feed and display it but I can't make an AJAX request? Also, how can a SaaS like ZenDesk offer a simple code snippet that allows uses to load a popover div with a form with AJAX-like functionality?

Comment: [Try reading about it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) and know what works, what doesn't, and how to make it work.

Comment: Try JSONP http://json-p.org/

Comment: If you are looking to use Ajax cross-domain please read [this article](http://www.justcode.us/2013/04/ajax-fetch-xml-external-file/).

Comment: 3 common ways to get around the SOP: Server-side proxy, CORS, JSONP. Google them. :)

Answer (score 2):

A client-side RSS reader (I assume you mean something like Google Reader) does not use javascript to fetch the rss feed. It uses php or some other server side language, which can get code from other places outside of the origin. Zendesk probably uses JSONP or something like that. If you are trying to make cross domain ajax calls, you should look into CORS, which allows you to do this if you control the servers at both ends. Really, you should look into these things before posting them on stackoverflow in the future.